# How to get JSON Result while adding user to Mysql Database using flask rest API

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, mysql-workbench

While I am adding a user in MySQL DataBase using Flask Rest API I am not able to get a JSON result?

I am able to add a user in MYSQL DataBase SuccessFully but not able to get a result in JSON file I need result like `{'user': 'added', 'Response' : '200 Ok'}`

My code is:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import mysql.connector
import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "This is database kind of thing "

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def adduser():
    result = [{'msg': 'success'}, {'stat': '200 ok'}]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_body = request.get_json()
        number = input_body['number']
        name = input_body['name']
        company = input_body['company']
        location = input_body['location']
        salary = input_body['salary']
        Operation = input_body['Operation']

        if Operation == 'adduser':
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="aviral")
            mycursor = connection.cursor()
            query = "INSERT INTO data (number, name, company, location, salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            val = (number, name, company, location, salary)
            mycursor.execute(query, val)
            connection.commit()
            return jsonify({'result': result})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My data is adding successfully in MYSQL WorkBench, while I am getting the error is now I only need JSON response in API Tester like Postman

Adding data using Postman

```
{
    "number": "12",
    "name": "Chetana",
    "company": "MDH",
    "location": "Masale",
    "salary": "23504",
    "Operation": "adduser"
}
```

But getting Result below, while data is added is MYSQL

```
return jsonify({'result': result})
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a second import for `jsonify` - which is wrong. The correct import is:

```
from flask import jsonify
```

Or you can access the `jsonify` method directly with:

```
flask.jsonify({'result': result})
```

Remove this import:

```
import jsonify
```

Comment: yes It helped a lot . I got Answer like {
  "result": [
    {
      "msg": "success"
    },
    {
      "stat": "200 ok"
    }
  ]
}

But if a Want answer like

{
  "result": [
    {
      "msg": "success"
      "stat": "200 ok"
    
}
]

Comment: That's because of how you've defined the result variable. Change that.